# Does .NET Standard 2.0 have a dedicated SDK and Runtime?

Tags: .net-standard

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet contains a list with the available SDKs and runtimes for .NET Core.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework contains a list with the available SDKs and runtimes for the old .NET Framework.

But on both pages and on (https://dotnet.microsoft.com in general) I couldn't find any SDKs and runtimes for .NET Standard 2.0. Do they even exist?

Comment: .NETStandard is supported by the .NETCore SDKs.  At runtime, the CLR loads the  netstandard.dll assembly that's specific to the ultimate target framework.  It simply [TypeForwardedTo] the supported types in .NETStandard to the target framework types.  The mapping occurs at jit-time.  
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/standard/assembly/type-forwarding

Comment: @HansPassant the URL you mentioned seems to be broken. The correct one should be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/type-forwarding

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no runtime for .NET Standard like for .NET Core and .NET Framework.